# If $cor(X,\epsilon) \approx 0$ in linear regression, can we conclude $X$ is exogenous?

Tags: regression, endogeneity

Suppose that we run the simple linear regression $Y = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon$.
I want to test whether the independent variable $X$ is exogenous.
If the correlation between the independent variable $X$ and the residual of linear regression $\epsilon$ is almost zero, i.e. $cor(X, \epsilon) \approx 0$,
can I then conclude that this simple test suggests that the independent variable $X$ is exogenous?

Comment: the issue is that in practice you don't observe $\epsilon$ (only $\hat{\epsilon}$) so you can never compute $\mbox{cor}(X,\epsilon)$

Comment: As said above, $\epsilon$ is unobservable so you need to rely on your own knowledge and use the common sense to decide about exogeneity.

Comment: The correlation between regressors and residuals (not errors) in a linear regression model estimated by least squares _is_ always zero. You cannot test exogeneity (conditional uncorrelatedness) without instrumental variables.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, as putting them all together answers my question. Is anyone willing to organize these together into an answer which I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear regression model is
$$
\boldsymbol{Y}  = \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}
$$
together with the **conditional uncorrelatedness** assumption $\mathbb{E}( \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}) = \boldsymbol{0}$.

If estimation of the parameters $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ proceeds by least squares, then the first order conditions (normal equations) are
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{X}'\left(\boldsymbol{Y}  - \mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}} \right) &= \boldsymbol{0} \\
\mathbf{X}'\hat{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}} &= \boldsymbol{0}
\end{align}
$$

where the last line indicates that the correlation between the residuals and the regressors is always zero for a linear regression model estimated by least squares. Thus this cannot form the basis of a test for the unconditional uncorrelatedness assumption in the linear regression model.

In order to test the exogeneity assumption, you will need access to instrumental variables. [See the Durbin-Wu-Hausman test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausman_test).